# Mean and variance of $\sqrt{X}$ given mean and variance of X

Tags: statistics

While it seems like a rudimentary question one should be able to google, I've tried every related search query I could think of and found nothing. Thus, given the mean and variance of X, how can one find the mean and variance of $\sqrt{X}$

Edit: X is normally distributed.

Comment: One cannot: the mean and variance of $X$ do not determine the mean of $\sqrt{X}$.

Comment: @Did Can it be done if the distribution is normal?

Comment: Square root of a random variable normally distributed? Sure about that?

Comment: @Did I mean if the random variable you're taking the square root of is normally distributed. X is normally distributed, and I need the mean and variance of $\sqrt X$

Comment: Yeah, and to consider the square root of a random variable, one needs that it is almost surely nonnegative. Do you think a normal random variable fits this condition?

Comment: But √X is defined correctly if and only if supp(X) is subset of R^+_0. Not for N(0,1), for example.

Comment: @Did I suppose that makes sense. I need it for a geometric mean, so I suppose I'll go ask a separate question on getting that geometric mean.