# Variance of the Euclidean norm of a vector of Gaussians

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, normed-spaces, chi-squared

Given a vector of correlated Gaussian random variables $\vec{X}=\left(X_1, ..., X_k\right)$ that are normally distributed $\vec{X} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\vec{\mu}, \Sigma\right)$ with arbitrary $\Sigma$ and $\vec{\mu}$ values what's the variance (i.e. the second central moment) of the random variable $\lVert X \lVert_2$?

---

From [length of Gaussian Random Vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605267/length-of-gaussian-random-vector) we know that the general probability density function of $\sqrt{Q(\vec{X})} = \sqrt{X^TAX}$ does not follow any known laws.

However I'm only looking for the variance. From the post we know that when analyzing the quadratic form (see linked post)
$$
Q(\vec{X})=\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\left(U_i+b_i\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\left(U_i^2 + 2b_iU_i + b_i^2\right)
$$
we obtain a superposition of [Chi-Squared-Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) and zero-mean Gaussian distributions since $\vec{U}$ is multivariate normal with identity covariance matrix and expectation zero.
Using [these rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties) we obtain:

- $var\left(U_i^2\right) = 2$ (Chi-Squared)
- $var\left(U_i\right) = 1$ (uniform Gaussian)
- $var\left(2b_iU_i\right) = 4b_i^2$
- $var\left(b_i^2\right) = 0$ (constant)
- $cov\left(U_i^2, 2b_iU_i\right) = E\left[2b_iU_i^3\right] = 2b_iE\left[U_i^3\right] = 0$
- $cov\left(U_i^2, b_i^2\right) = 0$
- $var\left(U_i^2 + 2b_iU_i + b_i^2\right) = 2 + 4b_i^2$, and hence

$$var\left(Q(\vec{X})\right) = \sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i^2(2 + 4b_i^2)$$

So the only step missing would to find $var\left(\sqrt{Q(\vec{X})}\right)$ given $var\left(Q(\vec{X})\right)$. Unfortunately it doesn't appear that simple according to [Mean and variance of $\sqrt{X}$ given mean and variance of X](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730133/mean-and-variance-of-sqrtx-given-mean-and-variance-of-x).

So how to move on with this?
Will the definition of the central moment be helpful? Assuming we are able to come up with the pdf of $\sqrt{Q(\vec{X})}$ I'm afraid this might only yield ugly integral terms that are impossible to solve or even approximate in the general case...

edit: fixed the variance of Chi-Squared to 2